# Delete operations in doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

For eg I have entities like User,Item, Image. User has many items. Item has many images.

Which delete option should I choose, cascade={'remove'} or onDelete=Cascade ?

Also I have life cycle callbacks on Image. I know the difference between above mentioned cascade options. I was wondering if I used onDelete=cascade option, on deleting a User object, will the life cycle callback like PostRemove() be called ?

Here are my entities:

```
//User.php
class User {
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="user", onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    private $items;
}

//Item.php
class Item {
   /**
   * @var User
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="items")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   * })
   */
   private $user;
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ItemImage", mappedBy="item",onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
   protected $images;

}

//ItemImage.php
class ItemImage {
   /* Setters and getter **/
   /**
   * @var Items
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="images")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   * })
   */
   private $item;
   /**
   * @ORM\PostRemove()
   */
    public function removeUpload() {
       unlink($this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->imageName);
    }
 }
```

My question is when a user is deleted, will all the items associated with user and images related to the items be deleted ? I also want the PostRemove() callback of Image entity be called when User is deleted ? Which option should I use, onDelete="cascade" or cascade={'remove'} for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

`onDelete='CASCADE'` will add an SQL level `ON DELETE CASCADE`. So yes, the images will be deleted from the table. This is very efficient because the database handles the deletes.

To have the listener called `cascade={'remove'}` is necessary. This makes Doctrine fetch the object's graph, which is slower.

Both options may be specified at the same time. In this case Doctrine will act as described in the last paragraph, but `DELETE`s not coming from Doctrine will cascade correctly, too; no listeners will be called in this case obviously.

I would tend to specify `cascade={'remove'}` only in this case to avoid accidental `DELETE`s without the listener being called (if there is no cleanup task for unreferenced files).

Details can be found in the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities).

Comment: so i should add cascade={"remove"} in both $User->items, $Item->images or only for $Item->images ? I am talking about the case when user is deleted.

Comment: You should add `cascade={"remove"}` to both `User->items` and `Item->images`. You may want to consider [additional cascade operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations), too, but they are less likely of interest.